# overload compound "+=" opertor as free function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

How to overload *+=* for *std::array* type so that I can do the following

```
std::array<int, 3> x = {1,2,3}; 
std::array<int, 3> y = {4,5,6};
x += y;
```

Comment: Have you tried `std::array<int, 3>& operator+=(std::array<int, 3>& lhs, const std::array<int, 3>& rhs) { ... }`?

Comment: `std::valarray` might be a better choice than `std::array` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to [overload an operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) for an existing type, without changing that type, you can opt for the non-member overload.

Here, you can try the templated approach, in order to cover all possible arrays if elements can be added:

```
template <class T, size_t n>
std::array<T,n>& operator+= (std::array< T, n>& l, const std::array<T, n> &r) {
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
        l[i] += r[i];
    return l; 
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/XRXGuP)